# How to hide console when displaying an image with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.5, windows-console

I have a simple code block that displays an image when the user press a button. When I save the script with `.py` extension, there is console at the background so I decided to save it as `.pyw` to hide it. Here is my code;

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

def open_image():
    im = Image.open("tobi.jpg")
    im.show()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+400+300")

buton = Button(root)
buton.config(text = "Show the image", command = open_image, activebackground = "yellow", bg = "lightgreen")
buton.pack()

mainloop()
```

I don't see `cmd` at the background since I save it as .pyw. However, when I click the button, just before opening the image I see console for a short time, then it dissappears. How can I avoid this, I want to hide console completely,

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do this through pure `tk` but if subprocess is an option then you can do the following. Not a very good solution, since you have to use the subprocess module just to open an image... but anyways....

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as s

root = tk.Tk()

def open_image():

    s.call(["tobi.jpg"], shell=True)

button = Button(root)
button.config(text="Show the Image", command=open_image, activebackground="yellow", bg="lightgreen")
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

alternatively you could use `os` and use `os.system("start my_file_name.jpg")` 
(assuming windows here)

With os.system the console will show but only very briefly.

Really doing the same thing, opening with `PIL` is just slower than others, so you see the console for a longer period.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the following code:`

```
import win32console
import win32gui
win=win32console.GetConsoleWindow()       # For closing command window
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)
```

This will close the cmd window at start itself, and will not show again. The cmd window may show for a very little time at first, as a blink, then it will not show. u can save in .py extention.

here the full code:`

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import win32console
import win32gui

win=win32console.GetConsoleWindow()       # For closing command window
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)

def open_image():
    im = Image.open("tobi.jpg")
    im.show()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+400+300")

buton = Button(root)
buton.config(text = "Show the image", command = open_image, activebackground     = "yellow", bg = "lightgreen")
buton.pack()

mainloop()
```